# Prometheus scraping from another machine

Tags: docker, prometheus, amazon-ecs, prometheus-node-exporter

I have node exporter running on a docker container in Amazon ecs, and I want to be able to scrape metrics from a different machine in the same network running Prometheus (aka not locally). How do I expose the port on docker and ecs to do so? Or is there a better way to do this?

edit: ecs access needs authentication, so just adding the ip to the yml file doesn't work

Comment: Did you check whether it expose metrics on 9100 port ?

Comment: It does, but I can only access it locally

Answer (score 0):

Since Prometheus and Amazon ECS were on the same network, port forwarding on the container allowed me to connect. There was no need to authenticate and just adding the ip:port to the config file for Prometheus worked.